# random error in docker when mounting a volume directory.

Tags: docker

Don't know why, but when mounting my keys.... They look different in the container then in the local host machine.

```
Joshuas-MBP:quikorderboot joshuacalloway$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

Joshuas-MBP:quikorderboot joshuacalloway$ docker run  -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -it --entrypoint=sh quikorderboot
/app # cat ~/.aws/credentials
[quikorder]
aws_access_key_id = ~NKYQ
aws_secret_access_key = ~gqr24WaP6m
/app # exit
Joshuas-MBP:quikorderboot joshuacalloway$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[quikorder]
aws_access_key_id = ~WJSQ
aws_secret_access_key = ~CS+XewIssfl
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on:

- the path represented with `~/.aws` in `-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws`: try a full explicit path (`/home/...` or `/Users/...`), knowing that if you are not in Linux (but are using docker on Windows or Mac), only `C:\Users` or `/Users` are mounted and visible in the (docker-machine created) `boot2docker` VM.
- **the default user** defined by the image: when you run a sh session, you are not `root`, but `joshuacalloway`: as such `~/.aws/credentials` is *not* `/root/.aws/credential`.

Note: generally aws credentials are passed [through environment variables](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/blog/tag/Docker)

```
    docker run -d \
     -e APP_CONFIG=application.config.example \
     -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
     -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
     -p 8080:5000 \
     eb-py-sample
```

Comment: it got fixed by restarting the default "docker-machine restart default"